# Macro to automatically save section name of previous section and next section

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, links, etoolbox

EDIT: I've edited the code that reproduces the anomalies, but I'll work on the code to more accurately depict the problem later on the day.

1. Weird spacing in index
2. Index doesn't appear in footlinks / isn't recognised as a section

The code won't show properly on this page (somehow 4 spaces doesn't do the trick), so I pasted it [here](https://gist.github.com/TobiasBouma/57a2ca2b9100b47d5056).

---

I'm trying to create a macro to save the **name** of the previous and next section automatically, so I can reuse it in my footer (with a link, but that's easily done through `\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{<anchor>}}` and anchors).

See the rfoot with the hyperlinks to different appendices.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}

% Set some commands that I'll use for all footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}

% Command for pageref for page/LastPage in footer
\cfoot{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{anchor.lastpage}}{ $\rightarrow$}}

% Global pagestyle commands
\fancypagestyle{contents}{
\lfoot{\textbf{Inhoudsopgave}}
}
\fancypagestyle{document}{
                    \rfoot{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave}}
                    \lfoot{\currentsection}
}

% By declaring the plain pagestyle explicitly, the first page is forced in terms of header and footer settings
% Not declaring this page style will not apply fancyhdr settings to the first page
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{\textbf{Inhoudsopgave}}
\cfoot{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{anchor.lastpage}}{ $\rightarrow$}}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

% header dummies which will be used in appendices - Auto-adjustment for variable page print of appendices
% It's also possible to use \getpagerefnumber and link thereto, but that gets you to the top of the page rather than the top of the appendix
% It's a small difference, but this yields a (slightly) prettier result
\fancypagestyle{a.appendix.headerref}{
                    \rfoot{\pbox{5cm}{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.b}{Naar begrippenlijst $\rightarrow$}  \\ \hyperlink{appendix.c}{Naar Index $\rightarrow$ }}}% 
                    \lfoot{\currentsection}
                    \fancyhead[C]{\hypertarget{appendix.a}{}}
}
\fancypagestyle{b.appendix.headerref}{
                    \rfoot{\pbox{5cm}{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.a}{$\leftarrow$ Naar \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{R}} commando's} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.c}{Naar Index $\rightarrow$ }}}% 
                    \fancyhead[C]{\hypertarget{appendix.b}{}}
}
\fancypagestyle{c.appendix.headerref}{
                    \rfoot{\pbox{5cm}{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.b}{$\leftarrow$ Naar begrippenlijst} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.d}{Naar Nesting $\rightarrow$ }}}%
                    \fancyhead[C]{\hypertarget{appendix.c}{}}
}
\fancypagestyle{d.appendix.headerref}{
                    \rfoot{\pbox{5cm}{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.b}{$\leftarrow$ Naar begrippenlijst } \\ \hyperlink{appendix.c}{$\leftarrow$ Naar Index }}}%
                    \fancyhead[C]{\hypertarget{appendix.d}{}}
}

\fancypagestyle{a.appendix.sep}{
                    \rfoot{\pbox{5cm}{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.b}{Naar begrippenlijst $\rightarrow$}  \\ \hyperlink{appendix.c}{Naar Index $\rightarrow$ }}}% 
                    \lfoot{\currentsection}
                    \fancyhead[C]{} % Reset the header from headerref construction
}
\fancypagestyle{b.appendix.sep}{
                    \rfoot{\pbox{5cm}{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.a}{$\leftarrow$ Naar \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{R}} commando's} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.c}{Naar Index $\rightarrow$ }}}% 
                    \lfoot{\currentsection}
                    \fancyhead[C]{} 
}
\fancypagestyle{c.appendix.sep}{
                    \rfoot{\pbox{5cm}{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.b}{$\leftarrow$ Naar begrippenlijst} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.d}{Naar Nesting $\rightarrow$ }}}%
                    \lfoot{\currentsection}
                    \fancyhead[C]{}
}
\fancypagestyle{d.appendix.sep}{
                    \rfoot{\pbox{5cm}{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.b}{$\leftarrow$ Naar begrippenlijst } \\ \hyperlink{appendix.c}{$\leftarrow$ Naar Index }}}%
                    \lfoot{\currentsection}
                    \fancyhead[C]{}
}



% Cross-references
\usepackage[pageanchor]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=red,
        hypertexnames=false,
        pdfhighlight=/N,
        pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}
        }

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{contents}
\hypertarget{document.toc}{}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

% Footer section name - Declare after ToC to keep section numbering intact
\newcommand{\currentsection}{}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsection{#1}\renewcommand{\currentsection}{#1}}

\newpage

\pagestyle{document}
\section{Week 1 - Intro \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}}}
\subsection{Objecten}
\subsubsection{Objecten met \'e\'en getal}

\newpage

% Clearpage to move floats as well, use newpage if you don't have floats on the last page
\clearpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

% I am using hypertargets from the preamble to make sure hyperref takes you to the top of the page and not the middle of it
% I've already explained why I picked this solution over \getpagerefnumber
\pagestyle{a.appendix.headerref}
\section{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{R} commando's}}

text

\newpage

\section{\textbf{Begrippenlijst}}
\pagestyle{b.appendix.headerref}

\newpage

\pagestyle{c.appendix.headerref}
\section{\textbf{Index}}

text

\newpage

\section{\textbf{Nesting}}

text

\end{appendices}

% Because the footer is printed last and there is a space between the appendices environment and the end of the document, we have to force this value or define set a manual environment. Setting a new environment would be the more tedious solution
                    \rfoot{\pbox{5cm}{\hyperlink{document.toc}{$\leftarrow$ Naar inhoudsopgave} \\ \hyperlink{appendix.b}{$\leftarrow$ Naar begrippenlijst } \\ \hyperlink{appendix.c}{$\leftarrow$ Naar Index }}}%
                    \lfoot{\textbf{Nesting}} % This will have to be set manually to circumvent cross-environment anomalies with fancyhdr
                    \lhead{}
                    \fancyhead[C]{\hypertarget{appendix.d}{}}

% Anchor on last page
\label{anchor.lastpage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe you have to catch the `\section` command and grab the section title in order to store it to some `\gdef`ed command.

Comment: Maybe it is just me but having compiled this I have no idea what it is supposed to look like or (therefore) what the problem is supposed to be. Is the issue specific to appendices? I'm assuming yes else you wouldn't have them in a minimal example but I just find it confusing. (Probably not helped by not understanding the language, mind.)

Comment: @cfr I want to automate creation of a dynamic footer which allows the user to navigate with hyperlinks through the appendix

Comment: How is that code supposed to do that? I don't see how you are using `\oldsection` or which parts of that are meant to be relevant. You use a custom pagestyle for each appendix. I don't understand how the other one you define is supposed to be used or how that one is meant to work with `\oldsection` etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Improved version**

I made some kind of a hack, redefining the `\section` command and introducing the possibility to refer to the previous and next section title name as hyperlinks. The titles are inserted automatically.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,onesided]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{imakeidx}%
\usepackage[heightrounded]{geometry}%
\usepackage[toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bbding}

\usepackage[pageanchor]{hyperref}%

\newrobustcmd{\ProvideBool}[2][false]{%
\newbool{#2}%
\setbool{#2}{#1}%
}%


\ProvideBool[true]{DocumentSectionAutoClearpage}%

\newrobustcmd{\EnableSectionAutoClearpage}{%
\setbool{DocumentSectionAutoClearpage}{true}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\DisableSectionAutoClearpage}{%
\setbool{DocumentSectionAutoClearpage}{false}%
}%


\definecolor{DocumentHyperLinkColor}{RGB}{255,0,0}%


\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=DocumentHyperLinkColor,
        hypertexnames=false,
        pdfhighlight=/N,
        pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}
        }


\AtBeginDocument{%
\setcounter{PrintIndexSectionCounter}{\number\value{IndexSectionCounterValue}}
\EnableSectionAutoClearpage%
}%



\makeatletter
\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section


% Providing section command with no optional argument

\newrobustcmd{\improvedstarredsection}[1]{% 
% No name reference to unnumbered sections 
%\BeforeSectionStarts{#1}%
\LaTeXStandardSection*{#1}%
}%



\newrobustcmd{\improvedsection@noopt}[1]{%
\BeforeSectionStarts{#1}%
\LaTeXStandardSection{#1}%
}%





% Providing section command with an optional argument
\newrobustcmd{\improvedsection@opt}[2][]{%
\BeforeSectionStarts{#1}%
\LaTeXStandardSection[#1]{#2}%
}%


% "True" section command
\newrobustcmd{\improvedsection}{%
\ifboolexpr{bool{DocumentSectionAutoClearpage}}{\clearpage}{}
\@ifnextchar[{\improvedsection@opt}{\improvedsection@noopt}
}%




%%%%%% Use the 'improved' section commands with forward/backward links
\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@ifstar{\improvedstarredsection}{\improvedsection}%
}
\makeatother




\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
 \if@twocolumn
 \@restonecolfalse
 \else
 \@restonecoltrue
 \fi
 \phantomsection%
  \section{\indexname}%
  \setcounter{PrintIndexSectionCounter}{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
  {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
  \parindent\z@
  % \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
  \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
  \columnseprule \z@
  \columnsep 35\p@
  \let\item\@idxitem}
{\if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi}%
\makeatother



\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\LastSectionInFile}{%
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string
     \setcounter{LastSectionValue}{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}%
   }%
}

\newrobustcmd{\IndexSectionInFile}{%
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string
     \setcounter{IndexSectionCounterValue}{\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}%
   }%
}%



\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{%
\LastSectionInFile%
\IndexSectionInFile%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\PreviousSectionName}{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{PreviousSectionCounter}}}%
\newrobustcmd{\CurrentSectionName}{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}}%
\newrobustcmd{\NextSectionName}{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{NextSectionCounter}}}%
\newrobustcmd{\NextSectionHyperLinkFormat}[1]{#1}%
\newrobustcmd{\PreviousSectionHyperLinkFormat}[1]{#1}%






\newrobustcmd{\GenerateNextSectionHyperlink}[3]{%
\DoIfNumInequal{\number\value{#1}}{\number\value{#3}}{%
\DoIfNumNotZero{\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}{%
    % Only set a link of the next section is not the index section%
  \ifnumequal{\number\value{#1}+1}{\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}{%
  \setcounter{InternalTitleCounter}{\number\value{#2}}%
  \addtocounter{InternalTitleCounter}{1}%
  \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{InternalTitleCounter}}{\NextSectionHyperLinkFormat{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{InternalTitleCounter}}}}%
  }{
    \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}}{\NextSectionHyperLinkFormat{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{#2}}}}%
  }}%
{%
  \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}}{\NextSectionHyperLinkFormat{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{#2}}}}%
  }%
  }% End of inner \DoIfNumInEqual
}%

\newrobustcmd{\GeneratePreviousSectionHyperlink}[3]{%
\DoIfNumInequal{\number\value{#1}}{1}{%
\DoIfNumNotZero{\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}{%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{#1}-1}{\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}{%
  \setcounter{InternalTitleCounter}{\number\value{#2}}%
  \addtocounter{InternalTitleCounter}{-1}%
  \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{InternalTitleCounter}}{\PreviousSectionHyperLinkFormat{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{InternalTitleCounter}}}}%
}{
%  \DoIfNumInequal{\number\value{#1}-1}{\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}{%
    \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}}{\PreviousSectionHyperLinkFormat{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{#2}}}}%
  }%
}{%
% Insert link in any case, since there is no bottom `Index` link
  \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}}{\PreviousSectionHyperLinkFormat{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{#2}}}}%
}%
}% End of outer \DoIfNumInequal
}% End of command



\newrobustcmd{\GenerateArrowHyperlinkToNextSection}[3]{%
\DoIfNumInequal{\number\value{#1}}{\number\value{#3}}{%
\DoIfNumNotZero{\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}{%
  \ifnumequal{\number\value{#1}+1}{\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}{%
    \setcounter{InternalTitleCounter}{\number\value{#2}}%
    \addtocounter{InternalTitleCounter}{1}% Look ahead
    \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{InternalTitleCounter}}{\ToNextSectionSymbol}%
    }{%
     \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}}{\ToNextSectionSymbol}%
    }%%
}{%
  \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}}{\ToNextSectionSymbol}%
}%
}% End of outer \DoIfNumInEqual
}%

\newrobustcmd{\GenerateArrowHyperlinkToPreviousSection}[3]{%
\DoIfNumInequal{\number\value{#1}}{1}{%
% But do nothing if the section number is equal to the total section counter value
\DoIfNumNotZero{\number\value{#1}}{%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{#1}-1}{\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}{%
  \setcounter{InternalTitleCounter}{\number\value{#1}}%
  \addtocounter{InternalTitleCounter}{-2}% Look ahead
  \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{InternalTitleCounter}}{\ToPreviousSectionSymbol}%
}{%
\hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}}{\ToPreviousSectionSymbol}%
}%
}{%
\hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}}{\ToPreviousSectionSymbol}%
}%
}% End of outer \DoIfNumInequal
}% End of command


\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhoudsopgave}
\newcommand{\LinkToContentsName}{\contentsname}
\newcommand{\LinkToIndexName}{Index}


\newrobustcmd{\DoIfNumNotZero}[3]{%
\ifnumequal{#1}{0}{#3}{#2}%
}%


\newrobustcmd{\DoIfNumInequal}[3]{%
\ifnumequal{#1}{#2}{}{#3}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\IfNumInequal}[4]{%
\ifnumequal{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%  
}%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%Additional counters%%%%


\newcounter{LastDocumentPageCounter}%
\setcounter{LastDocumentPageCounter}{1}

\newcounter{IndexSectionCounterValue}%
\newcounter{PrintIndexSectionCounter}%




\newcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}% No resetting%%%
\setcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{0}%

\newcounter{NextSectionCounter}% No resetting%%%
\setcounter{NextSectionCounter}{0}


\newcounter{CurrentSectionCounter}% No resetting%%%
\setcounter{CurrentSectionCounter}{0}

\newcounter{LastSectionValue}

\newcounter{InternalTitleCounter}

\newrobustcmd{\refcommand}[1]{%
\nameref*{#1}%
}%



\newrobustcmd{\CurrentSectionSymbol}{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{\HandRight}}~}
\newrobustcmd{\ToNextSectionSymbol}{\textbf{\textcolor{DocumentHyperLinkColor}{\HandRight}}~}
\newrobustcmd{\ToPreviousSectionSymbol}{\textbf{\textcolor{DocumentHyperLinkColor}{\HandLeft}}~}



\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd{\WriteUniqueTextLabelContent}[2]{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\newlabel{#1}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{\unexpanded{#2}}{}}%
}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\BeforeSectionStarts}[1]{%
\stepcounter{CurrentSectionCounter}%
%%%%% Check first whether there is already a previous section
\ifnumequal{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{1}{% Yes, section number is zero
\setcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{1}%
}{%
\setcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}
\addtocounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{-1}
}
% CurrentSectionCounter > 1
% Set Target to current section
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{CurrentSection::\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{}%
\WriteUniqueTextLabelContent{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{#1}%
% Set correct numbers 
\setcounter{NextSectionCounter}{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}
\ifnumequal{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{\number\value{LastSectionValue}}{}{%
\addtocounter{NextSectionCounter}{1}%
}%
\phantomsection
}%


\newrobustcmd{\InsertToIndexSymbol}[4]{%
% #1: Number of IndexSection
% #2: Number of CurrentSection
% #3: Text for link to previous section (normally left hand?)
% #4: Text for link to next section (normally right hand?)
\ifnumequal{\number\value{#1}}{0}{%
% Do nothing, since there is no Index section (value of #1)!
}{%
  \ifnumless{\number\value{#1}}{\number\value{#2}}{%
    \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#1}}{#3}%
    }{% Not lesser, check greater then....
    \ifnumgreater{\number\value{#1}}{\number\value{#2}}{%
      \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#1}}{#4}%
    }{%
      % Do nothing, since both counters are equal!!!!
    }%
  }% End of \ifnumless is not true, i.e. other branch >= value of #2 
}%
}%



\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}%


\fancypagestyle{contents}{%
  \lfoot{\begin{tabular}{l}%
    \CurrentSectionSymbol\textbf{\contentsname} \tabularnewline
    \tabularnewline%
    \tabularnewline%
    \tabularnewline%
\end{tabular}
}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{}%
}



\fancypagestyle{normalpages}{%
  \lfoot{\begin{tabular}{l}%
    \CurrentSectionSymbol\textbf{\contentsname} \tabularnewline
    \tabularnewline%
    \tabularnewline%
    \tabularnewline%
\end{tabular}
}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{}%
}


\fancypagestyle{FootLinks}{%
  \lfoot{\begin{tabular}{l}%
    \CurrentSectionSymbol\CurrentSectionName \tabularnewline
    \tabularnewline%
    \tabularnewline%
    \tabularnewline%
\end{tabular}
}%
\cfoot{\begin{tabular}{c}%
      \thepage /\pageref{LastPage}\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{anchor.lastpage}}{~\ToNextSectionSymbol}       \tabularnewline
      \tabularnewline%
      \tabularnewline%
      \tabularnewline%
\end{tabular}
}%
  \rfoot{\begin{tabular}{@{}rl}
    \hyperlink{document.toc}{\ToPreviousSectionSymbol} &     \hyperlink{document.toc}{\LinkToContentsName} \tabularnewline %
    \GenerateArrowHyperlinkToPreviousSection{CurrentSectionCounter}{NextSectionCounter}{1} & \GeneratePreviousSectionHyperlink{CurrentSectionCounter}{PreviousSectionCounter}{1} \tabularnewline%
     \GenerateArrowHyperlinkToNextSection{CurrentSectionCounter}{NextSectionCounter}{LastSectionValue} & \GenerateNextSectionHyperlink{CurrentSectionCounter}{NextSectionCounter}{LastSectionValue} \tabularnewline%
%     \DoIfIndexSection{PrintIndexSectionCounter}{CurrentSectionCounter}{\ToPreviousSectionSymbol}{\ToNextSectionSymbol} &
     \InsertToIndexSymbol{PrintIndexSectionCounter}{CurrentSectionCounter}{\ToPreviousSectionSymbol}{\ToNextSectionSymbol} &
     \hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}{\InsertToIndexSymbol{PrintIndexSectionCounter}{CurrentSectionCounter}{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}}{\refcommand{CurrentSection::Title::\number\value{PrintIndexSectionCounter}}}} \tabularnewline%
  \end{tabular}%
}%
\fancyhead[C]{} % Reset the header from headerref construction    
}%




\makeindex

\begin{document}
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{document.toc}{}%

\pagestyle{contents}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagestyle{normalpages}

\section{First Section}
\blindtext[2]
\index{Schr\"odinger}
\section{Another section}
\blindtext[3]

\section[Short Section Title]{Another section with a not so short title}



\section{The three witches}
\index{Shakespeare}
\index{Macbeth}


\clearpage %



\clearpage

\begin{appendices}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{FootLinks}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

\section{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{R} commando's}}

\blindtext%

\section*{And I am a completely unnumbered section and do not appear in the foot links ;-)}


\section{Begrippenlijst}
\blindtext%


\printindex% Note: \printindex behavious like an extra section

\section{\textbf{$E = mc^2$}}
\blindtext%

\section{Dummy 1}
\section{Dummy 2}
\blindtext%
\clearpage
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comments will be added soon!

Features:

- The foot link to the next and previous secion are omitted if the standard link to index section is just one section ahead or before. The link then points
  to the section +- 2 ahead/before
- `\printindex` behavious like a section entry now, with TOC item
- If there is no `\printindex`, no bottom index link is inserted. Remove 
  the `.aux` file in this case manually!

Comment: It is meant for sections only, not for chapters...

Comment: Applying your `\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section` etc. code nested in `AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}` makes this functional in real documents as well (it will exclude section names of the actual document). The last hiatus will be to conditionally set the links to have the same format as what I had in my example document.

Comment: @Euyris: I meant to improve my solution for other purposes also, but I had not enough time this morning.

Comment: No problem. I added the solution and a suggestion for which I can't get the syntax right to the original post.

Comment: @Euryis, I believe, that `appendix` uses `\section*` instead of `\section`. Basically, it is sufficient to apply the redefinition of `\section` to `\section*` as well, apart from some problems with the starred command. Do yo really stick to `\usepackage{appendix}`?

Comment: The rest of your solution works just fine with the regular `\section` (also the part in the `appendices`), so I don't see how the asterisk would change anything?

Comment: @Euryis: I will look at your edits later on, what they really change.

Comment: What's the best way to store the section names of two sections ahead and two sections before? Embed more ifnumequal statements?

Comment: @Euryris: I am working out another version of my code, which should it make easier to adapt, also providing a better counting scheme, therefore remove some errors/warnings. Basically you should get the name of the sections ahead with another counter (value) of `CurrentSectionCounter` + 2, but of course, you should check whether there is such a total section value at all and most probably fix the possible value at the end to the maximum section value. The same holds the other way round for sections before the current section.

Comment: I've applied this solution to my actual document and it's working great! Except for two things: 1) I cannot use any commands like \textbf and \textcolor anymore (although the print. color, etc. works correctly). I am sure there's a workaround for this. 2) the global font size is messed with somehow, so it's required to set the font size to \small for all elements... I can imagine this is a problem to some people.

Comment: @1010011010: I am still working at a  different solution, which will be more configurable than my old answer, but I was rather busy the last days. I have time this afternoon....

Comment: I like it. If there's an easy way to include a large amount of previous/next sections (say, up to 5 sections ahead/behind, but cleaner would be to include a function to set infinite sections ahead/behind), you could turn this into a package? :)

Comment: @1010011010: I considered the extension to more than one section look ahead/back, after your question about +2 or -2 sections ahead/before, but where do you want to place the links to them, let alone of 5 sections? It is rather a matter of paper/screen size ;-)

Comment: That's up to the user to decide, isn't it? Two more things: 1) When I am in the appendix and I'm 1 section off of the index, it will show the link twice... This can be easily fixed with more writes to the aux file to determine the section number about the index and change the specific cases of that section number -1 and +1 for the right page style. 2) For people that only want to use this in the appendix, can declare `FootLinks` along with the `\appendix` command, instead of the `appendix` environment (which also has other advantages/more customizability, also inside the `appendix` package).

Comment: @1010011010: I will look after it. Perhaps it is really worth as a package.

Comment: @1010011010: I know about the double index link just about in the section next to the last one. You are right, that this will be solvable if the section numbers are compared, given that **Index** is always the last one.

Comment: @1010011010: Your second request about the `\appendix` `FootLink` pagestyle -- you suggest that I should redefine the `\appendix` command such that it defines/applies the `FootLinks` style automatically?

Comment: The second request is more of a recommendation for other people that wish to apply this within the `appendix` *only*. Regarding the double index link: You can use the `PreviousSectionCounter` and the `NextSectionCounter` maybe and measure them when the Index is active. Then you will have the previous and next section numbers so the index doesn't have to be last. ;-)

Comment: @1010011010: The counters mentioned by you contain values of course, but they are not directly connected to a section named `Index`. By the way, as soon as one would `\printindex` the whole linking to index in the footers breaks. I have to redefine the `\printindex` command.

Comment: @1010011010: I updated the code, this addresses (somehow) the other question you posted regarding the `\printindex`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: This really should be turned into a package!

Comment: @Daniel: I will try, but it takes time ;-)

Comment: I have a new question concerning your solution: Is there any meaningful function to automatically start a new page every time the \section command is issued?

Comment: @1010011010: Just say `\DisableSectionAutomaticClearpage` in `\AtBeginDocument` and the clearpages will vanish. Or remove `\EnableSectionAutomaticClearpage` ;-) Meaningful? It is feature which can be switched off ;-)

Comment: Your code has worked perfectly so far, except for one thing. I found a graphical anomaly, possibly related to a different spacing in the Index environment ?!?! The page I'm referring to is shown here: Index page --> http://i.imgur.com/YC2thIj.png and normal page --> http://i.imgur.com/qzGrU2C.png . This seems to affect the index only.

Comment: Hmm the index isn't recognised as a section either... (footlinks seem to skip index)

Comment: The `Index` link is not shown on the index pages, as you requested that in a previous comment. Which graphical anomaly do you mean?

Comment: As I can not see what you have used, I can only suspect a spurious ` ` or other character either in your or in my code.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I found the solution to the spacing problem: `\columnsep 35\p@` adjusts the spacing of the footer when it is used along with `\dimexpr(-\height+\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox)/2`.

Comment: As far as I can remember, I did not introduce `\columnsep` somewhere ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I meant that I wanted the index to show up as if it were a section... so the same effect as when using the regular `\section{Index} <index stuff here>`

Comment: @1010011010: Well, you mean removing `twocolumn` feature?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14606/discussion-between-1010011010-and-christian-hupfer).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If chat doesn't work for you, we can also continue the discussion here.

Comment: Sorry, I am in a supermarket right now, just typing with a  pen on my smartphone... it's no joy ;-) I am back at my desk in about half an hour

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I ran into a new problem recently. When I use `splitindex` (e.g. `\makeindex[name = x, title = Another index]`, the footlinks will show "Index" for each Index (both the normal index as well as other indices that I named differently). The input that I specified in `\makeindex` somehow doesn't reach NextSectionTitle and PreviousSectionTitle (?)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I fixed this problem by locally containing expansion. `\unexpanded` keeps `\indexname` from expanding, which will result in wrong section names when "looking ahead". Usage of `\unexpanded` only where necessary (e.g. when using `textcolor{color}`: `\section{\unexpanded{\textcolor{blue}{text}}}`), worked for me.

Comment: I once had `\newrobustcmd{\indexname}` which troubled me also, so switched back to `\renewcommand{\indexname}{...}`, after then it worked. I think your application of the code changed so far from my original posting that I can not help further. I still work on the package, but it there are so many other things to do, I have very few spare time right now ;-)