# How to get chapterthumb work in KOMA-Script?

Tags: xetex, texlive, chapters, koma-script, chapterthumb

I came from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124495/chapter-thumbs-or-tabs-in-book-class/124581#124581) as I was looking for a way to get chapterthumb work according to the d[irections](http://www.komascript.de/node/200).

I manually installed the `chapterthumb.sty` package into the texlive2013 distribution. However, the MWE didn't work -- error: `File chapterthumb.sty' not found. \pagestyle`
The textedior (TexStudio) shows that the package is present when I hover the mouse over the `\usepackage{chapterthumb}`. I don't know whether this is enough to tell that a package is recognized by texlive. 
What am I missing?

Note:
Xetex compilation.

**Update**
I have Windows 7 platform, based Chirstian Hupfer's adivse I put the `.sty` file in the *working* directory, this worked on the v0.1 chapterthumb package but not on v0.2.

**Request**
To show in a MWE code:

1. How one can stop chapterthumb from appearing in table of contents, appendix chapters?
2. How to change the text of the chapterthumb from `Chapter 1` to `Introduction`, `Chapter 2` to `Materials & Methods`, and so forth, as promised in the linked website above.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Am Anfang beginnt es}\dots
\chapter{Weiter}\dots
\chapter{Und weiter}\dots
\chapter{Und noch weiter}\dots
\chapter{Und immer weiter}\dots
\chapter{Geht die Reise}\dots
\chapter{Hinaus}\dots
\chapter{Und weiter hinaus}\dots
\chapter{Immer weiter hinaus}\dots
\end{document}
```

**Update**
there is no guarantee that the code in the MWE nor in solution to work because of the KOMA-script update. The new version of chapterthumb package is no more based on the scrpage2 package, but rather on its successor scrlayer package. Please refer to http://www.komascript.de/chapterthumbs-example for more info.

Comment: Where did you install `chaptertumb`?

Comment: C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\tex\latex\chapterthumb\chapterthumb.sty

Comment: Did you rerun `texhash` or whatever it is called on Windows? Alternatively, as a bypass solution: Install it in your current working directory, i.e. where your document `*.tex` is placed.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I put the `.sty` in the working directory, but then I got a different error: `Missing \begin{document}. -`

Comment: You did not try to run `xelatex` on `chapterthumb.sty`, did you? That would not work, since a package itself does not provide the `\begin{document}` command

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, No, I ran `xelatex` on `.tex` file.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hmm, it worked when I put the `.sty` in the working directory that belong to v0.1. By Markus Kohm on the linked website but not to the updated v0.2! very strange. Most probably something with the *updated* package itself.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, v0.1 is not desired, the v0.2 handles a very critical issue concerned with stopping chapterthumb manually.

Comment: @doctorate: v0.2 runs without any problems on my computer. Is your KOMA installation also up to date?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, what i want is to show in code how to stop chapterthumb from appearing in TOC, appendix, etc. and at the same time how to change the text of the chapterthumb itself; instead of `Chapter 1` -> `Introduction`, `Chapter 2` -> `Materials & Methods`, etc. Is that possible with v0.2?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I updated the KOMA 3 packages in texlive 2013, restart, nothing changed.

Comment: @doctorate: I will look later on that request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14961/discussion-between-christian-hupfer-and-doctorate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** 07/10/2014: **
The question above and the solution are continued in a follow - up question, to be found here: [How to get chapterthumbs match their chapter titles in KOMA-Script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184011/how-to-get-chapterthumbs-match-their-chapter-titles-in-koma-script/184058#184058), where a better way is provided.

The `chapterthumb` style can be removed by disabling the `pagestyle{scrheadings}` from KOMA classes and enabling it later on again where needed.

In order to print the chapter title instead of `Chapter 1` etc, one way is to store the current chapter title to be a label content and later use `\nameref*`to refer to that label name inside a redefined `\chapter` (catching the [] and * versions) and redefine `\chapterthumbformat` command from `chapterthumb.sty`. (For more details about the labelling method, see my question (and answer) to [Writing text content as labels and refer to them with \nameref*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176605/writing-text-content-as-labels-and-refer-to-them-with-nameref))

**Note: This could lead to very long chapterthumb boxes, however!**

**Note 2: Source of an error will be the resetting of the chapter number!**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{nameref}%
\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}

%
\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter%
\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\refcommand{chapter::title::\number\value{chapter}}}%

\makeatletter

\newcounter{totalchaptercounter}%

\newrobustcmd{\WriteChapterTitleToAux}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{totalchaptercounter}%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\newlabel{chapter::title::\number\value{totalchaptercounter}}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{\unexpanded{#1}}{}}
}% End of writing to AUX file
}%

\newrobustcmd{\refcommand}[1]{%
\nameref*{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\chapter@noopt}[1]{%
\WriteChapterTitleToAux{#1}%
\LaTeXStandardChapter{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\chapter@opt}[2][]{%
\WriteChapterTitleToAux{#2}%
\LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}%
}%


\newcommand{\unstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\chapter@opt}{\chapter@noopt}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredchapter}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}
}%



\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}%
}%


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}%
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\chapter{Am Anfang beginnt es}\dots
\chapter{Weiter}\dots
\chapter{Und weiter}\dots
\chapter{Und noch weiter}\dots
\chapter{Und immer weiter}\dots
\chapter{Geht die Reise}\dots
\chapter{Hinaus}\dots
\chapter{Und weiter hinaus}\dots
\chapter{Immer weiter hinaus}\dots
\clearpage%
\pagestyle{plain} % Or any other user defined style
\appendix%
\section{Appendix A}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you please care about a recently posted question on the same code above in the *linked* questions?