# How to get chapterthumbs match their chapter titles in KOMA-Script?

Tags: xetex, chapters, koma-script, thumb-index, chapterthumb

This is an add-on question to a [previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183560/how-to-get-chapterthumb-work-in-koma-script-using-v0-2-not-v0-1) one on chapterthumbs. Please consider the MWE below, the chapterthumbs are not matching the chapter titles (Discussion should appear instead of Materials & Methods), so how to:

**Objectives**

- Match chapterthumbs with their chaptertitle -- answered
- Activate chapterthumb on Abstract/Bibliography in the MWE -- answered
- Suppress chapterthumb on curriculum vitae in the MWE -- answered
- The advancement of the thumbs should *advance* along the whole right edge of the page - answered!

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{nameref}%
\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}

%
\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter%
\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\refcommand{chapter::title::\number\value{chapter}}}%

\makeatletter

\newcounter{totalchaptercounter}%

\newrobustcmd{\WriteChapterTitleToAux}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{totalchaptercounter}%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\newlabel{chapter::title::\number\value{totalchaptercounter}}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{\unexpanded{#1}}{}}
}% End of writing to AUX file
}%

\newrobustcmd{\refcommand}[1]{%
\nameref*{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\chapter@noopt}[1]{%
\WriteChapterTitleToAux{#1}%
\LaTeXStandardChapter{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\chapter@opt}[2][]{%
\WriteChapterTitleToAux{#2}%
\LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}%
}%


\newcommand{\unstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\chapter@opt}{\chapter@noopt}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredchapter}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}
}%



\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}%
}%

%=====================Bibliography=============================
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@article{rand_objective_1971,
    title = {Objective criteria for the evaluation of clustering methods},
    volume = {66},
    issn = {01621459},
    url = {http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2284239?uid=3737864&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103234673533},
    doi = {10.2307/2284239},
    pages = {846},
    number = {336},
    journaltitle = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
    shortjournal = {J Amer Statist Assoc},
    author = {Rand, William M.},
    urldate = {2013-12-18},
    date = {1971-12},
    keywords = {Comparing partitions, Rand, statistics}
}

@article{hubert_comparing_1985,
    title = {Comparing partitions},
    volume = {2},
    issn = {0176-4268, 1432-1343},
    url = {http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01908075},
    doi = {10.1007/BF01908075},
    pages = {193-218},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Classification},
    shortjournal = {J Classif},
    author = {Hubert, Lawrence and Arabie, Phipps},
    urldate = {2013-12-18},
    date = {1985-12-01},
    langid = {english},
    keywords = {{ARI}, Comparing partitions, Consensus indices, Measures of agreement, Measures of association, statistics, Statistics, general}
}   
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
%==================================================
\title{Title of the Dissertation}
\author{Author Name} 
\publishers{Faculty Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}%
\tableofcontents %chapterthumb:no
\chapter{Acknowledgements} %chapterthumb:no
\chapter{Abstract}\dots
\clearpage
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{Introduction}\dots
Sample text here cited \parencite{hubert_comparing_1985}, which is different from \textcite{rand_objective_1971}.

\chapter{Materials \& Methods}\dots 
\chapter{Results}\dots 
\chapter{Discussion}\dots
\backmatter
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\clearpage%
\pagestyle{plain} % Or any other user defined style
\chapter*{Curriculum Vitae} %chapterthumb:no
\end{document}
```

**MWE Output**
[image]

**Note**

- `chapterthumb` is not yet supported by TexLive2013, and hence should be manually installed
- The `chapterthumb.sty` [v0.1](http://www.komascript.de/komascriptbuchexamples) was used in the above MWE and not the updated [v0.2](http://www.komascript.de/node/200) package on windows 7 platform.

**Update**
there is no guarantee that the code in the MWE nor in solution to work because of the KOMA-script update. The new version of `chapterthumb` package is no more based on the `scrpage2` package, but rather on its successor `scrlayer` package. Please refer to http://www.komascript.de/chapterthumbs-example for more info.

Comment: Well, `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` screw the whole chapterthumb with chapter titles up (sorry for that language, as well as for `\chapter*{}`, since the code was not meant for such chapters. I never liked the `\mainmatter`, `\frontmatter` and `\backmatter` commands, because they perform some settings... and I have look into the `.cls` file, what they are actually doing.

Comment: so what do you suggest instead?

Comment: Let us continue in chat, alright?

Comment: Then let us stay here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\frontmatter` and starred chapters stresses the former version I gave to another question of OP some days ago, so that solution has to be revised and is given here. 
First of all, I dropped the possibility for `\chapter*{}` to make chapter thumbs, it was necessary to redefine `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` to be on the safe side, that not a changed starred chapter command is used and increases the `totalchaptercounter` accidentally.

- Do not change the chapter number somewhere, this leads to wrong references
- Do not use a `\chapter*{}` between two normal `\chapters`, regardless whether
  `\chapter[shorttitle]{longtitle}` or `\chapter{longtitle}`
- Do not change the `\totalchaptercounter` somewhere, this messes the counting
  up.
- **Never use `\frontmatter` to switch to roman page numbers, it does strange
  setup I could not figure out so far, use `\pagenumbering{roman}` instead.

I could not test any individual occurence *what could be if someone does something* ... of course

---

Here is the changed code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{nameref}%


\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}


\newrobustcmd{\refcommand}[1]{%
\nameref*{#1}%
}%

\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\refcommand{chapter::title::\number\value{chapter}}}%

\makeatletter

\newcounter{totalchaptercounter}%

\newrobustcmd{\CreateUniqueChapterLabel}[1]{% Well, `unique` as it can be ;-)
\refstepcounter{totalchaptercounter}%
\label{chapter::title::\number\value{totalchaptercounter}}%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter%

\newcommand{\chapter@noopt}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter{#1}%
\CreateUniqueChapterLabel{#1}% Must appear after chapter title is done
}%

\newcommand{\chapter@opt}[2][]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}%
\CreateUniqueChapterLabel{#2}% Must appear after chapter title is done
}%


\newcommand{\unstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\chapter@opt}{\chapter@noopt}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredchapter}[1]{%
\lohead[]{}% Clear the headers -> no chapterthumb here 
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}%   
}%

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardTOC\tableofcontents%
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\LaTeXStandardChapter}%
\LaTeXStandardTOC%
\endgroup%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardLOF\listoffigures%
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\LaTeXStandardChapter}
\LaTeXStandardLOF%
\endgroup
}%

\let\LaTeXStandardLOT\listoftables%
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\LaTeXStandardChapter}
\LaTeXStandardLOT%
\endgroup
}%

\makeatother


%==================================================
\title{Title of the Dissertation}
\author{Author Name} 
\publishers{Faculty Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle%
\pagestyle{plain}%
%%%% Set roman page numbers here, but do **not** use \frontmatter!!!!!!
\pagenumbering{Roman}% or \pagenumbering{roman}%
\tableofcontents %chapterthumb:no
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Acknowledgements} %chapterthumb:no
\chapter{Abstract}\dots
\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter% Can be done safely
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{Introduction}\dots
\begin{figure}
\caption{dummyfigure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Materials \& Methods}\dots 
\chapter{Results}\dots 

\begin{table}
\caption{dummy table}
\end{table}

\chapter{Discussion}\dots
\blindtext
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain} % Or any other user defined style

\chapter*{Curriculum Vitae} %chapterthumb:no
\end{document}
```

**Edit -- Updated version**

- Adding `\chapter*{}` to the toc is easy, use `\addcontentsline` for this
- `\printbibliography` is more difficult, because it is basically an unstarred
  section, so the chapter number is not increased. This has to be done either
  manually or with amendments to `\printbibliography` and writing explicitly 
  a label with the the content `Bibliography` to the `.aux` - file.
- I introduced a `toggle` flag `UseChapterThumb` which can be set to `true` or `false`, however, it is manually set to `true` in the beginning and after changing to `false` it has to be set again, if chapter thumbs are desired.
- the bibliography **must** currently be the last 'chapter' in the file, there
  **must not** be another `\chapter{}` after the bibliography, `\chapter*{}` poses no problem however.
- The chapter thumb marks are spread over the total right page according to the number of chapters. However, if there many chapters, the space for a thumb will become very small and the text is either wrapped or partially gobbled, if there is a chapter title with long word(s).

---

Here is the updated code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{chapterthumb}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{nameref}%
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{totcount}
\bibliography{bib}%

\regtotcounter{chapter}%


\AtBeginDocument{%
\ifnumequal{\number\totvalue{chapter}}{0}{%
\renewcommand{\chapterthumbwidth}{\paperheight}%
\renewcommand{\chapterthumbskip}{\paperheight}%
}{%
\typeout{There are \number\totvalue{chapter} chapter in this document}%
\renewcommand{\chapterthumbskip}{\paperheight/\number\totvalue{chapter}}%
\renewcommand{\chapterthumbwidth}{\paperheight/\number\totvalue{chapter}}%
}%
}%

\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}

\newrobustcmd{\SetChapterThumbHeader}{%
\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\ClearChapterThumbHeader}{%
\lohead[]{}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\refcommand}[1]{%
\nameref*{#1}%
}%

\newtoggle{UseChapterThumb}%
\toggletrue{UseChapterThumb}%

\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\refcommand{chapter::title::\number\value{chapter}}}%

\makeatletter

\newcounter{totalchaptercounter}%

\newrobustcmd{\CreateUniqueChapterLabel}[1]{% Well, `unique` as it can be ;-)
\refstepcounter{totalchaptercounter}%
\label{chapter::title::\number\value{totalchaptercounter}}%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter%

\newcommand{\chapter@noopt}[1]{%
\iftoggle{UseChapterThumb}{\SetChapterThumbHeader}{\ClearChapterThumbHeader}
\LaTeXStandardChapter{#1}%
\CreateUniqueChapterLabel{#1}% Must appear after chapter title is done
}%

\newcommand{\chapter@opt}[2][]{%
\iftoggle{UseChapterThumb}{\SetChapterThumbHeader}{\ClearChapterThumbHeader}
\LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}%
\CreateUniqueChapterLabel{#2}% Must appear after chapter title is done
}%


\newcommand{\unstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\chapter@opt}{\chapter@noopt}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredchapter}[1]{%
\ClearChapterThumbHeader% Clear the headers -> no chapterthumb here 
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}%   
}%

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardTOC\tableofcontents%
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\LaTeXStandardChapter}%
\LaTeXStandardTOC%
\endgroup%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardLOF\listoffigures%
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\LaTeXStandardChapter}
\LaTeXStandardLOF%
\endgroup
}%

\let\LaTeXStandardLOT\listoftables%
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\LaTeXStandardChapter}
\LaTeXStandardLOT%
\endgroup
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardPrintBibliography\printbibliography%


\newrobustcmd{\commonprintbibliographysetup}[1][]{%
\iftoggle{UseChapterThumb}{\SetChapterThumbHeader\refstepcounter{chapter}}{\ClearChapterThumbHeader}
\LaTeXStandardPrintBibliography[#1]%
\iftoggle{UseChapterThumb}{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\newlabel{chapter::title::\number\value{chapter}}{{\thepage}{\thepage}{Bibliography}{}}%
}%
}{}%
}%



\newrobustcmd{\printbibliography@@noopt}{%
\commonprintbibliographysetup[]%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\printbibliography@@opt}[1][]{%
\commonprintbibliographysetup[#1]%
}

\renewcommand{\printbibliography}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\printbibliography@@opt}{\printbibliography@@noopt}%
}%

\makeatother


%==================================================
\title{Title of the Dissertation}
\author{Author Name} 
\publishers{Faculty Name}

\begin{document}


\maketitle%
\pagestyle{plain}%
%%%% Set roman page numbers here, but do **not** use \frontmatter!!!!!!
\pagenumbering{Roman}% or \pagenumbering{roman}%
\tableofcontents %chapterthumb:no
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Acknowledgements} %chapterthumb:no
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}%
\chapter*{Abstract}\dots
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}%
\cleardoublepage
\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}% Again here...
\mainmatter% Can be done safely
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{Introduction}\dots
\begin{figure}
\caption{dummyfigure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Materials \& Methods}\dots 
\chapter{Results}\dots 

\begin{table}
\caption{dummy table}
\end{table}

\chapter{Dummy Chapter}%            Please remove this afterwards
\chapter{Another Dummy Chapter}%     Please remove this afterwards

\chapter{Discussion}\dots
\blindtext
In his book \cite{lamport94} Leslie Lamport
\cleardoublepage

\togglefalse{UseChapterThumb}% Switch off chapter thumbs for this section
\chapter*{Curriculum Vitae} %chapterthumb:no

\cleardoublepage
\toggletrue{UseChapterThumb}%
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]




\end{document}
```

### [image]

Comment: the abstract and acknowledgements should be without numbers, hence the number of chapter introduction according to the above code is `3`; how to reset that to `1`? Problem is, if I use a starred version of acknowledgments and abstract they will not be in the TOC.

Comment: other issue, I put \printbibliography after \backmatter, how to make chapterthumb include the list of bibiliography too? any known issues with \backmatter? I will try to update the MWE to include a dummy bibliogragphy.

Comment: other issue, when I applied the above code the bibliography didn't show up again in the TOC. If it appears it should be also without a chapter number like abstract and acknowledgments.

Comment: Well, `\printbibliography` does not generate an entry to toc, as well as starred chapters. Both is possible, I will do it

Comment: I updated the code to `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` to get an entry in the TOC if everything is fine.

Comment: I managed to let the first two sections be starred, with entries to the toc, but `\printbibliography` as with chapterthumb is really tough :-(

Comment: @doctorate: I updated the code

Comment: the updated code throws an error: `File ended while scanning use of \etb@xargdef`, I use `biber`, though, so this might be the problem. However, I get the same error even when `bibtex` was used. I am puzzled now.

Comment: Did you delete `*.aux` file before?

Comment: yes, I deleted all before every fresh compilation. One more issue I have noticed which can be a good cause to abandon the whole chapterthumb  idea, that the thumbs themselves are not *distributed* equally over the right edge of the page. That is, as discussion thumb is reached in my case it was about in the middle of the page when it should be at the end. So it seems to be very complicated then to divide the number of thumbs over the vertical length of the page. Is this possible?

Comment: If got the source of the error above: There was a missing `}`, I will update immediately, your other request... well, let's see ;-)

Comment: I mean if you look at the introduction thumb it starts right from the top of the right edge, as chapters move on, there is a  *disproportional* increment leaving the *last* chapter, whether discussion  or bibliography, not really on the end of the edge, did you notice that?

Comment: @doctorate: Yes, I noticed that, I have no idea why that occurs so far.

Comment: @doctorate: I spread the thumbs over the whole right margin of the margin, dynamically adapting the height (actually the width!!!) to the numbers of chapters there are in the document. See my note above the updated code

Comment: the document compiles well, but I lost the thumbs altogether! I think I have now a thin border on the right edge of the page instead of a thumb.

Comment: @doctorate: keep that version as a backup file, I will upload again, perhaps, I made again some accidental editing/deleting in the posted code

Comment: @doctorate: Done!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15008/discussion-between-christian-hupfer-and-doctorate).