# Bold page numbers with revtex

Tags: page-numbering, revtex

I would like to print page numbers bold (that's an example) wherever they appear. My naive MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\textbf{X}}
%\usepackage{microtype}
%\renewcommand*{\thepage}{X}
\begin{document}
    foo
\end{document}
```

This does work. However, as soon as I use a few other packages such as `microtype` (uncomment first commented line), this breaks. This can be fixed by uncommenting the second commented line, suggesting that it's not the messing with `\thepage` per se which breaks things. Still, I lose the effect that I want.

With the formatting, the `aux` file looks like this:

```
....
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \def document{1}\let \futurelet \@let@token \let \protect \relax \protect \edef m{bx}\protect \xdef \OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 {\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 }\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 \size@update \enc@update 1\egroup }{}{}{}}
```

So probably, this command in `revtex4-1.cls` messes things up:

```
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{\thepage}{}{}{}}}%
```

How can I fix this line to make things right?

**Update:**
This creates a proper `.aux` file, but of courses messes up the document's page numbers:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\string\textbf{X}}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
    foo
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding formatting to `\thepage` should be the last resort.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % mock text

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\@oddhead}{\thepage}{\textbf{\thepage}}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@evenhead}{\thepage}{\textbf{\thepage}}{}{}%
}
\let\latex@pageref\pageref
\renewcommand{\pageref}[1]{\textbf{\latex@pageref{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This text has \pageref{LastPage} pages.

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `.aux` file has

```
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{2}{}{}{}}
```

as it should.

Something more is needed if you use `hyperref`, but it's not in your question.

If you really want to go on the `\textbf{\arabic{page}}` road, then do it properly:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\textbf} % make \textbf survive \edef

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\textbf{\arabic{page}}}
```

Comment: The OP stated (in a comment, so maybe not easy to find) that he/she wants the page numbers to be bold *everywhere*, including in cross-references.

Comment: @Mico It's quite easy, too.

Comment: Thanks! But you do agree that if I do not touch the definition of `\thepage`, then I do need to care about any (future) potential use of `\thepage`, be it through `\pageref` (which you cover), other `hyperref` functionality (which you mention) or other other custom macro (I could think of some back-referencing script, or a package breaking tables across pages and referencing them from one another). And I do not see any downside to formatting `\thepage` by changing its definition, so I like my answer better. (Oh, I see one downside: `\pagenumbering` resets `\thepage`. But I can deal with that.)

Comment: @bers Then do it properly: `\usepackage{etoolbox}`, then `\robustify{\textbf}` and finally `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\textbf{\arabic{page}}`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I count that as an acceptable answer despite it being a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [Writing text content as labels and refer to them with \nameref*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176605/writing-text-content-as-labels-and-refer-to-them-with-nameref/176606#176606):

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\unexpanded{\textbf{X}}}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
    foo
\end{document}
```

This seems to actually work!