# Reference Chapter Number

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a book with multiple chapters (in different sections, if that is relevant). Chapters are numbered. I want a way to transform the chapter name into the chapter number, someplace else in my text. That is, I want to say "See Chapter 4, which covers magic in depth". The chapter that is responsible for covering magic in depth may change over the course of the editing process: I want the chapter number to change with it automatically. I don't want to refer to the name alone. I am using LaTeX's autonumbering for chapters. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample 1}
    This is covered in more detail in Chapter X.
\chapter{Sample 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Package `nameref` and `\nameref{chapterlabel}` should work, where `chapterlabel` is something you stated right after `\chapter{Magic}` , say e.g. `\label{magicchapter}`. But your request is a little confusing since there seem to be wanted two different behaviours of the reference?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think `\nameref*{CurrentSection::Title::<something>}` and printing the section counter along with it, is what he's looking for. Similar to how you determined the CurrentSection counter at the Index for the request I made here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175054/macro-to-automatically-save-section-name-of-previous-section-and-next-section

Comment: @1010011010: Perhaps it is similar, perhaps the answer I gave to your question is useful too.

Comment: @1010011010 , your answer is something I would prefer not to get into: my knowledge of LaTeX is self taught, rather limited, and does not extend to many of the commands used in your version. If there is a simpler way to solve my problem, one that doesn't require pages of code, that would be lovely. I will write it if I have to, but I am hoping that there is a simpler method.

Comment: While reading through variables scales linearly with the amount thereof, comprehending the amount does not. I think what you're asking for is very straightforward and would be significantly easier than you think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LaTeX provides this cross-referencing scheme out-of-the-box. Place `\label{<label>}` after a counter that can be referenced (like a chapter, section, subsection, theorem, ...) and use it elsewhere as `\ref{<label>}`. This will only return the counter number and nothing else:

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{xparse,nameref}
\NewDocumentCommand{\chapref}{s m}{Chapter~\ref{#2}\IfBooleanF{#1}{ \nameref{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample 1}\label{ch:first}
This is covered in more detail in \chapref*{ch:second}. Also see~\ref{ch:second}.

\chapter{Sample 2}\label{ch:second}
This is covered in more detail in \chapref{ch:first}. Also see~\ref{ch:first}.
\end{document}
```

The above example sets the `\label`s after every `\chapter`. They're referenced using `\ref{<label>}`, which clearly just returns the chapter number. However, with the addition of [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) we can grab hold of the chapter title as well, referencing it as `\nameref{<label>}`. A combination of `\ref` and `\nameref` is incorporated in what I defined as `\chapref`, which translates to `Chapter~\ref{<label>} \nameref{<label>}`. The latter `\nameref` is conditional on whether you call `\chapref` with/without a star `*`.

The above example can be made fully-functional with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), providing inter-document hyperlinking.

The option `[openany]` was just so the two chapters fit on subsequent page and is not needed in your document.

Comment: Werner, in my thesis I have separated latex files that representing the chapters. How can I refer the chapters in this case?

Comment: @Gilson: You have to place the `\label`s inside the files after the `\chapter` command.

Comment: I did it, but couldn't work

Comment: @Gilson: That doesn't help much.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Werner's code, you could also use one of the packages which set this up for you automatically. `fancyref` and `cleveref` are two which spring to mind. For example:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{fancyref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample 1}\label{chap:first}
This is covered in more detail in \fref{chap:second}. Also see~\ref{chap:second}. \Fref{chap:second} covers this in excruciating detail.

\chapter{Sample 2}\label{chap:second}
This is covered in more detail in \fref{chap:first}. Also see~\ref{chap:first}. \Fref{chap:first} covers this in more detail.
\end{document}
```

[image: References using <code>fancyref</code>]

Note that `chapter` is added automatically if the `chap` prefix is used in the label, and that `\Fref` and `\fref` produce capitalised and non-capitalised output. (I believe that `cleveref` automatises things further but I've not used it myself.)